# Вопросительные слова "как" и "когда" как части речи

Tags: грамматика, как

Какими частями речи являются слова написанные прописными буквами?

*КАК прекрасен сад весной! КОГДА ты вернешься из отпуска?*

Мне кажется, что КАК - частица, КОГДА - союз, так ли это?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Как* - это восклицательная частица, Вы правы.

*Когда* - наречие, которое для проверки можно заменить другим наречием.

Ср.:Завтра ты вернёшься из отпуска?

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В приведенном Вами примере "как" - местоименное наречие.

Ожегов, Шведова

***Как***

> 1. ***мест. нареч. и союзн.*** сл. То же, что ~им образом (см. образ 1) . К. вы поживаете?
> 2. мест. ***нареч. и союзн. сл.*** В ~ой степени, насколько. К. недавно это было?
> 3. мест. ***нареч. и союзн. сл***. До ~ой степени, до чего. Удивительно, к. красиво.
> 4. ***частица. Употр. для выражения удивления и оценки. К! Ты опять здесь!***
> 5. ***частица.*** При гл. сов. вида означает внезапность действия в прошлом (разг. ) . Он к. закричит!
> 6. ***союз.*** Выражает сравнение, подобно кому-чему-н. Белый к. снег. Такой же, к. прежде.
> 7. ***союз.*** Употр. при отождествлении: в качестве кого-чего-н, будучи кем-чем-н. Советую к. друг.
> 8. союз. Употр. в составе вводных сочетаний и предложений. К. говорят. К. например.
> 9. ***союз.*** Выражает временные отношения. К. вспомнишь, страшно становится (всякий раз, когда) . Прошёл год, к. мы виделись (с того времени, когда) .
> 10. ***союз.*** После отрицательных или вопросительных слов и выражений означает ограничение, кроме, только. Больше некому, к. тебе. Кто, к. не мы?

Comment: См.: дополнение.

Comment: Екатерина, а с какого источника вы взяли ту информацию?

Answer (score 0):

*Как* — в функции сказуемого. Это не восклицательная частица.

*— Я завтра уезжаю.
— **Как** уезжаешь?!*

Вот восклицательная частица.